# How to deploy Swagger Ocelot API Gateway in Azure -> Application Error

Tags: azure, docker, swagger, gateway, ocelot

I'm trying to create working solution with Swagger Ocelot API Gateway and deploy it on Azure as a hybrid of Azure App Service and Azure Container Instances.
Backend services are deployed to ACI, a service that runs containers. Docker images are stored and deployed to containers (Azure Container Registry).
Virtual Network is used to deploy our containers into with two subnet (one used for containers and the other one for gateway). The gateway is not deployed into this virtual network, but access to it via the gateway-subnet, which communicates with the backend-subnet.
Gateway is deployed as Azure App Linux Service, which communicates to our backend services via their private IPs by configuring the VNet Integration.
However, the App Service is not working. It gives an application error and in the log stream is the following:

at SwaggerOcelot.Gateway.Program.<>c.b__1_0(IConfigurationBuilder config) in \SwaggerOcelot.Gateway\Program.cs:line 17
2022-01-27T09:27:54.820243802Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
2022-01-27T09:27:54.820248402Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
2022-01-27T09:27:54.820257202Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
2022-01-27T09:27:54.821977012Z    at SwaggerOcelot.Gateway.Program.Main(String[] args) in SwaggerOcelot.Gateway\Program.cs:line 11
2022-01-27T09:28:05.940519859Z Could not open output /home/logs/dumps/coredump. 2 No such file or directory

I wonder whether the deployment process is not correct.